# Python class property subproperties

Tags: python, properties, decorator

I would like to implement something like this:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 0

    @my_property(_("multilang_name"), _("multilang_description"))
    def test(self):
        return self._value

    def test(self, value):
        self._value = value

t = test()
t.test = 10
print t.test #should print '10'
```

So it was possible to:

1. get all my_property properties from given class
2. access given my_property class property's localized name and description (using gettext)
3. use these properties like normal Python property

How to write my_property decorator? Or maybe there is better way to implement this functionality?

Thank You.

Comment: The properties name/class shouldn't really be internationalised, as it's code, not presentation. This is usually the case for the docstrings too, but if you really want those to be internationalised, you're better off modifying the `help()` command to run the returned docstring through `gettext`

Comment: Hmmm. I understand it is not good idea to do such things, but I just wanted to automatize some work. I need set of plugins and want plugin manager to automatically find proper actions and create the UI. Anyway still not sure how to do this.

Comment: So you want the GUI/UI of the app you're creating to be internationalised? In that case, look into [Python i18n](http://docs.python.org/library/i18n.html), which will automatically handle the translation of the UI. If you mean you want your code translated, may I ask why? It's pretty much conventional to code in US English, regardless of where you're from. Still, modifying or rolling your own version of Python's inbuilt `help()` command will handle the docstrings. For the actual code, you *can* access the dicts of functions/vars in a class etc to modify them, but it'll just cause more issues.

Comment: No I just want my class properties to be connected with some actions. So manager class could list all actions and give it's user friendly (i.e. localized) name and description. For example It maight be useful for argparse module so I could get list of program actions their localized name and description in help.

Comment: Maybe the easiest will be to have some dict-like object with action name, localized name and description.